# ng-repeat in table and conditional tr

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a collection of elements of different types. I want to iterate them using ng-repeat, and conditionally draw the right tr per each type.

I can't use ng-repeat-start since I want to use virtual scrolling and none of the libraries I found supports the start/end concept.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mx6v8j98/1/, which doesn't work. here is the HTML part:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in itemsList" ng-switch="$even" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                <div ng-switch-when="true">
                    <td>{{item}} is even</td>
                    <td>even content</td>
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-default>
                    <td>{{item}} is odd</td>
                    <td>odd content</td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In my real world case, I have many td with complex content, so I don't want to use ng-if/ng-switch-when on each

Update: I can put the ng-repeat on the `<tbody>` tag, but that looks ugly and I'm not sure what the consequences are regarding styling

Update II: In my case, the 'tr' tag itself is rendered differently according to a condition

Comment: It's because of the divs inside the table. plunkr complains in the editor about vodoo mode. it works without them if you use ng-ifs for each td (not very nice), http://plnkr.co/edit/2rMSCcIZJwYWD4CoUk25?p=preview

Comment: i would change data structure instead

Comment: @toskv: "I have many td with complex content, so I don't want to use ng-if/ng-switch-when on each"

Comment: @MaximShoustin: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in another answer, `<div>` is not allowed as a child element of `<tr>`.

You are clearly trying to use `<div>` as a logical container for `ng-switch-when`, but since `ng-switch-when` (and `ng-switch-default`) supports [multi-element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement-), you don't need this container:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch="$even">

  <td ng-switch-when-start="true">{{item}} is even</td>
  <td>even content 1</td>
  <td>even content 2</td>
  <td ng-switch-when-end>even content last</td>

  <td ng-switch-default-start>{{item}} is odd</td>
  <td>odd content 1</td>
  <td>odd content 2</td>
  <td ng-switch-default-end>odd content last</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: wow! where did you learn that there's ng-switch-when-start? I can't find it in the docs

Comment: @IttayD, I edited the question with the link to documentation. In a nutshell, any directive that supports `multiElement` (in its directive definition object) can be used with `-start`/`-end` to denote the range of elements. It's a feature of Angular. For example, `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` are such directives - try it.

Comment: In my case, the tr itself is rendered differently (classes, attributes). Do you have a solution for that? if not, i'll accept your answer as it fits my original question.

Comment: @IttayD, not sure exactly what you mean... you could still use `ng-class` and `ng-attr-foo` and based it on `$even` variable. Seems like a separate question though

Comment: Good to know about `-start/-end` stuff. @IttayD, for complex content, you'd create your own directive, which can be very flexible. Here is something I implemented as a property table. The table contains property elements. https://github.com/stanleyxu2005/dashing/blob/master/src/tables/property-table/property-table.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot put `<DIV>` within `<TR>` but before `<TD>`.

**Solution 1**: Put conditional expression in every `<TD>`.

```
<!-- TDs for even row -->
<td ng-if="$even">{{item}} is even</td>
<td ng-if="$even">even content</td>

<!-- TDs for odd row -->
<td ng-if="!$even">{{item}} is odd</td>
<td ng-if="!$even">odd content</td>
```

**Solution 2**: For fairly complex table structure, you'd consider create your own directive to represent row cells.